# How do I input M-shift-return in Aquamacs

Tags: macos, emacs, aquamacs

I'm trying out org-mode and the tutorial says Meta-Shift-Enter is bound to org-insert-todo-heading, and I did a describe-function to verify it is bound to that key in my environment

I tried inputting it using escape as meta, so I typed ESC, then holding shift down, enter. I got an error message that ESC- is not defined. Is there a special way I should input this key sequence?

Comment: That problem is not specific to Aquamacs. The same sequence of keys is not recognized as `<M-S-return>` by Emacs under Linux either, though holding down `Shift` and `Alt` and then pressing `Return` works. I do not know why the translation of `Esc` to `Meta` doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the Aquamacs FAQ, specifically the [section on the meta key](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AquamacsFAQ#toc6)?